# Merge someone else's changlist into my client?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I clones this repository: https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/tree/master/traitlets

This pull request is waiting to be accepted:
https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/pull/70

How do I merge it into my client so that I don't have to wait for its acceptance?

---

```
~/src: rm -rf traitlets/
~/src: git clone https://github.com/ipython/traitlets.git
Cloning into 'traitlets'...
cd taremote: Counting objects: 4005, done.
^Rceiving objects:  31% (1242/4005)
remote: Total 4005 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 4005
Receiving objects: 100% (4005/4005), 717.15 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1951/1951), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
~/src: cd traitlets/
~/src/traitlets: git remote add SylvainCorlay https://github.com/SylvainCorlay/traitlets.git
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SylvainCorlay wants to merge 5 commits into ipython:master from SylvainCorlay:Descriptors

`SylvainCorlay:Descriptors` indicates the GitHub user and branch of the fork.

So you can simply `git remote add SylvainCorlay https://github.com/SylvainCorlay/traitlets.git` to add the user's repository as a remote (assuming you already have a local clone of the upstream repo). Then fetch it with `git fetch SylvainCorlay`. Afterwards you can `git checkout SylvainCorlay/Descriptors` or merge the changes locally.

If you didn't clone it, simply clone the form and `git checkout Descriptors`.

Comment: Thanks!  Any ideas why this fails? `~/src/traitlets: git checkout SylvainCorlay/Descriptors`  Returns: `error: pathspec 'SylvainCorlay/Descriptors' did not match any file(s) known to git.`   I cloned the repo and successfully added his repo as a remote as shown in my question.

Comment: @NeilG make sure to `git fetch SylvainCorlay` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the diff from a PR by just adding ".diff" (or ".patch") to the end of the URL:

> https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/pull/70.diff

Then you can apply that to your repo.

Comment: Thank you!  I hate being lazy, but do you know the diff/patch command offhand?

Comment: Something like `patch -p1 < file.diff` (from the repo's root directory)